# Если UserAgent = 'Mozilla', значит это бот (скрипт)?

Tags: бот, useragent

Если значение UserAgent на сервере точно соответствует значению "Mozilla" можно это считать фиктивным запросом (ботом, скриптом и т.д) ?

Comment: По юзерагенту ничего точно считать нельзя

Comment: А с чего вы так, собственно, решили? Реальные запросы не пробовали отслеживать?